# How can I push git to directory in repository directly?

Tags: git

I made directory called `testDir` in repository like the picture below and I also made a test project. I want to push test project to `testDir` directly. For this, I typed command below.

[image]

**git init**

**git add README.md**

**git commit -m "first commit"**

**git branch -M main**

**git remote add origin https://github.com/MontaKr/test/tree/main/testDir**

but it says **fatal: repository 'https://github.com/MontaKr/test/tree/main/testDir' not found**

or sometimes it says **error: failed to push some refs to ~~~**

I don't know what is wrong and how can I push project to directory?

Comment: Git doesn't care about directories when pushing. It can only push _commits_ (and not partial commits).

Comment: Short answer: no, a directory inside a git repository is not in itself a git repository. A git repository always encompasses the whole tree depth under it (except if you use submodules, which you don't want to use at this point, they are a very specialized thing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should:

- clone your GitHub repository locally, using the repository URL `https://github.com/MontaKr/test` (and not a subtree)
- copy your local testDir folder in it
- add, commit and push

Comment: thank you for your reply. But couldn't understand meaning of `copy your local testDir folder in it`. Can I be more clear about this?

Comment: @DgUZH You mentioned " I also made a test project. " I assume that local project is in a local folder somewhere. I propose to copy it to the testDir of the clone repository.

Answer (score 1):

I’m currently reading [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2), so while I’m not completely knowledgeable, I’ll take a swing with what I know

@VonC ‘s answer is the way to do it, but why?

**Git uses the .git directory to build the repo.** You made a new repo *(using ‘git init’)*, which by consequence has a **different .git directory**.

So although the link was off, as VonC pointed out, the original way still wouldn’t have been legal - ***I think***.

Usual flow would be:

1. Clone your repo. Use the link GitHub gives you - find it by clicking on the green code button
2. Make changes via commits
3. Push it back to the GitHub repo

This way the original .git directory is still intact, and no foul no harm.